# Why was this answer to "numpy-like-package-for-node" deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation, specific-answer

About a month ago, I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451155/8967612) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412537/numpy-like-package-for-node):

> I created my own library here:
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/lynx-js
> Usage:
>
> ```
> var lynx = require("lynx-js")
> var arr = new lynx.NdArray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
> console.log(arr.mul(2).toString()) //array([[2,4,6],[8,10,12]])
> ```

The answer immediately got downvoted and deleted by a moderator. But no reason for deletion was specified. What is the reason for deletion? Is it because of the promotional nature? I find this unlikely, as there were one or two other promotional answers that did not get deleted, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61933250/11064188). 
Or is it just a problem with grammar, spelling, etc.?

Comment: FYI: The answer was marked as spam. I'm not sure whether or not that is shown to the author. Apparently not?

Comment: At least two of your other visibile answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65769054/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62185523/) contain self-promotion. Is it possible you have additional deleted answers that also include self-promotion? If so, it is possible that the moderator reviewed your posting activity and concluded that you were providing too many self-promoting answers. See [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for more information.

Comment: @IanCampbell The answer appears to be indeed deleted as spam/rude/abusive. AFAIK, when a post is deleted for any other reason, it's _not_ hidden from view. When a post receives a red flag (spam, etc.), a mod can choose to explicitly not apply the penalty. I think they usually do that when it's not clear-cut (e.g., borderline spam) which is probably what happened here.

Comment: Additionally, the two answers you refer to promote different "products". So, unless there are other deleted answers, it doesn't seem like the OP has an excessive amount of posts promoting a certain "product".

Comment: @41686d6564 My experience is that *any* spam or R/A flag is enough to hide a post from 10k users, but someone more experienced can likely provide a definitive answer. I totally agree, based only on the visible answers and the one deleted answer, the level of self-promotion seems reasonable. I was just asking if there might be more deleted answers to justify the decision.

Comment: @41686d6564: Even weirder: it was marked as rude or abusive, *not* spam. But I guess a red flag's a red flag...

Comment: @41686d6564: The penalty is applied only when the red flag threshold of 6, or a single moderator-binding flag, is reached. This penalty can be averted by a moderator using a binding *delete* vote instead.

Comment: @IanCampbell So basically, it was deleted because I have not just 1, but 2 or 3 self-promotional answers?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220289/299295)?

Comment: @41686d6564 Truth be told, seeing a promotional answer for a Node.js library *on a C++ question* seems excessive just by itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Except that it isn't a c++ question, it's a node.js question.

Comment: @Gimby I was referring to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918260/c-least-nonzero-trit-in-ternary-number/65769054#65769054), which was part of the set dug up by Ian Campbell. Title: C++. Body: C++. Tags: C++. Promotional answer: Node.js.

Comment: Also the question asks "Note, I'm not asking for 'what is the best package to do xyz'. I'm just wondering if there is a technical reason there is no package to do this on node, a social reason, or no reason at all and there is just a package I missed." There is no way to answer that by showing some code or link to a library.

Comment: Both other promoted libraries were open source. What's the difference between that and a non-promotional answer?

Comment: There are problems with the question itself. It's borderline a recommendation question and not very focused and opinionated. It could be shortened and made much more clear. I guess that the problems with the answer come partly from problems with the question.

Comment: The answer that MisterMiyagi dug up is just plain *terrible*. There's a time and place for inserting node.js into absolutely everything, and that question is not it.